# Can we configure karate.waitForHttp(url)

Tags: karate

**What am I trying to do?**

- During test flow I have situation where I need to wait atleast 20 minutes before my service comes up, I would like to use the call `karate.waitForHttp(url)` to wait till my service comes and then proceed to next feature that runs tests agains this service.

**What did I try?**

- I tried using `karate.waitForHttp(url)` and Isee from logs it waited for 2 minutes and reported error.
- For now I am trying to achieve this by writing some custom java/js code that internally waits till the service is up.

**What am I looking for?**

- Please can I get some details on how to use `karate.waitForHttp(url)`.
- Can we configure the wait time for the call `karate.waitForHttp(url)` ?

~thanks

Answer (score 0):

Karate 1.0 will expose a Java API to make HTTP requests, so you should be able to easily write your own loop to wait: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop#java-api

To see how the existing code handles this - see `public static boolean waitForHttp(String url)` [here](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/develop/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/shell/Command.java#L212). Should be easy to adapt the code for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, will look into `jbang`. For now I have something similar, to the way `public static boolean waitForHttp(String` has been implemented